# JIRA - Only required fields are displayed on Create Issue Screen

Tags: jira

I installed and uninstalled several JIRA plugins and without any screen configuration changes all fields which are not required disappeared from Create Issue Screen for only one user (me (smile)). My Create Issue Screen looks like that right now. **Why there are only required fields?**

[image: Create Issue Screen with only required fields]

All other users have correctly displayed all fields. There is a difference between my page source code and source code of other users. **I have one more `<div>` for each hidden field**. For example priority field is covered by one more `<div>` which make it hidden.

```
<div id="qf-field-priority" class="qf-field" style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

There was hidden fields through Configure Fields button, which was disabled by script. **Enable Configure Fields button > show all field and disable it, resolved the problem.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    AJS.toInit(function(){
        // init on load
        AJS.$("#qf-field-picker-trigger").hide();
    })
    JIRA.bind(JIRA.Events.NEW_CONTENT_ADDED, function (e, context) {
        // init on refresh
        AJS.$("#qf-field-picker-trigger").hide();
    });
})(AJS.$);
</script>
```